# Java ProcessBuilder: OutputStream(Reader) of a process never gets ready() for *certain* commands

Tags: java, shell, cygwin, outputstream, processbuilder

I've written an interface to call shell commands from Java for testing purposes. For a few commands, that works quite fine, but for others, the OutputStream of the process never gets ready(). Does anyone have an explanation ? I give the full code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.err.print("cmd: ");
String line=in.readLine();
```

The following are all fine for "cat -n", not for "sed s/a/e/"

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(("bash -c \""+line+"\"").split(" ")));
// ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(("cmd /C "+line).split(" ")));
// ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/C",line);
// ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c",line);
// ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(line.split(" ")));
```

Interaction with the process:

```
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
BufferedWriter toP = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream()));
BufferedReader fromP = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
for(line = in.readLine(); line!=null; line=in.readLine()) {
    toP.write(line+"\n");
    toP.flush();
    System.err.println("stdin: \""+line+"\"");
    while(!fromP.ready());                            // sed hangs, cat doesn't
    System.out.println("result: \""+fromP.readLine()+"\"");
}
```

One can find plenty of information on ProcessBuilder issues, and for most of them, wrapping stdin and stdout into different Threads seems to be a solution. But if indeed this is the solution, then why ?

An further: Does anyone have an explanation why the straight-forward approach fails and under what circumstances this occurs ? From the example, I can rule out that it is the way the arguments are presented or the specific shell (cmd/bash).

I'm working with Java 1.6 on a Windows7 machine with Cygwin installed, hence both bash and cmd. Could that be a Cygwin issue ?

Comment: The obvious reason seems to be buffering of the consuming command. "sed -u s/a/e" works. As a quick fix, the busy waiting block at `while(!fromP.ready());` needs to write, say, a "\n" in every iteration. The problem is that if the program doesn't wait for input but does some calculation, the buffer may easily overflow, so this is not ideal, either.

Comment: The padding trick won't always help, though. I tried it when calling senna (ml.nec-labs.com/senna/), without any success at all.